# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting (o que devo fazer?)

Tags: python

Estou resolvendo uma questão simples de calculo de imposto em um salario:

```
sal=float(input('digite o valor:'))
if   sal>3000:
    percent=0.25
elif sal>2000:
    percent=0.20
elif sal>1000:
    percent=0.10
else         :
    percent=0.5
imposto=sal*percent
salliquido=sal-imposto
print('salário: R$%6.2f'%sal)
print('imposto: R$%6.2f'%imposto)
print('salário liquido: R$6.2f'%salliquido)
```

Porém quando dou run o python retorna o seguinte erro:

```
digite o valor:1500
salário: R$1500.00
imposto: R$150.00
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Onde estou errando?

Comment: No último `print` faltou o `%` antes do `6.2`. Aproveitando, dê uma olhada em [*f-string*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), que pode te ajudar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

você esqueceu de colocar um `%` no ultimo print apos o cifrão( R$ )
o seu código esta assim:
`print('salário liquido: R$6.2f'%salliquido)`

e o certo seria assim:
`print('salário liquido: R$%6.2f'%salliquido)`

é so uma falta de atenção mesmo!